# Nginx path component load a subdomain, sibling projects at Root Folder (Drupal and Laravel)

Tags: drupal, nginx, laravel-3, proxypass

I've tried already several ways that I've found over the internet but I still didn't manage to work.

What I want is, i have a server configuration for the url:
**www.domain.com** where I have installed and configured a Drupal website.

I also have a subdomain, **api.domain.com** where I have installed and running a Laravel application.

*IMPORTANT:*

- And each of this projects, have it's own nginx configurations.
- Both projects are siblings projects at my Root directory.

### What I need

That all requests for the URL *www.domain.com/api* are requested to the subdomain *api.domain.com* and if is a specific url like *www.domain.com/api/option1/options2* request *api.domain.com/option1/option2* **without** redirecting the user.

So I basically I need that the NGINX configuration for the Drupal **ignore** all the requests to the */api* URL and request to the subdomain

### Why I need

I need to have all subdomains and everything else under the same domain, because I only have the SSL to use on **www.domain.com** and not ***.domain.com**

---

I don't know if this is the best approach for my problem, but if you have any other suggestions I'm open.

Thanks in advance.

---

### My own Answer

I couldn't reply my own question so here is the answer I manage to work.

```
location   ^~ /api/  {
    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$   /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://api.domain.com;
}
```

And this will also force the final trailing slash.

If you don't want to force the trailing slash just remove the last one at the *location*

Comment: seems fine with me, but does it have to be `break` ? did `last` not work ?

Comment: I don't know why, but with the last did't work, it keeps open my Drupal website.

Comment: Although this seems to work, now I'm having another problem. When I try to access www.domain.com/api/option1 it works, but when I try to access www.domain.com/api/option1/ it redirects me to www.domain.com/option1. Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

well there's 2 ways, simplest would be creating a location in the root domain that proxy's to the api subdomain

```
location /api {
  rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 last; # removing the `/api` prefix from the URI before proxying
  proxy_pass http://api.example.com;
}
```

The second method is to write the whole configuration of the subdomain inside that location, to avoid doing that proxying

```
location ^~ /api(.*) {
  root /path/to/api/root;
  # add any config you believe should be here
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$1; # depends on your api way of functioning
}
```

Tell me if I misunderstood something or got something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So I decided to go with the first option, so I can keep the NGINX configurations for each project in separated files, but I got this error for the first option:   2014/02/01 15:59:01 [error] 21942#0: *4 the rewritten URI has a zero length, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.com"

Comment: ok try `domain.dom/api/` with an extra slash, does that work ?

Comment: No, same error:  1 the rewritten URI has a zero length, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.com"

Comment: forgot using `last` in the rewrite, fixed it in my answer, does that make any difference ?

Comment: Mohammad, thanks again for helping me with this, but still happening the same error.

Comment: ok, if this last change doesn't work then I don't know why it's not working, so i hope it does

Comment: Still having the same error...But than I decided to start trying everything and managed something to work, I'll answer bellow

Comment: I couldn't answer because I have a new account, could you please see my updated question and see if what I got is correct? Also how do I force the trailing slash at the end, to make www.domain.com/api be forced to www.domain.com/api/